# Using gsub to get the second instance of numbers from a string

Tags: r

I have the following string with text, numbers, numbers and text from which i wish to extract the second set of numbers. An example of the string can be seen below;

```
myexample
'Details/200000/100/random-name/moredetails'
```

From this I wish to get the number 100 out (all text and both numbers will change so cant just do a simple gsub here)

So to do this I need to create a gsub which says everything up until the first instance of numbers and then everything after the second set of numbers, then keep the 2nd instance. What i have if as below but I cant quite get it to work;

```
myexample = gsub('(.+)[[:digit:]]/[[:digit:]](.+)', '\\2', myexample)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
myexample <- 'Details/200000/100/random-name/moredetails'

gsub('.+[[:digit:]]+?/([[:digit:]]+).+', '\\1', myexample)
#> [1] "100"
```